# Why does string equality not working in this Python code as expected?

Tags: python

**Note:** Before you go and downvote or close my question, or mark it a duplicate, let me assure you that I have looked a dozens and dozens of similar questions on SO and Googled but after more than an hour, I still haven't solved this problem. No other answer solved my problem.

**Question**
I have this Python code:

```
text = ''
text += '<' + '/' + '>'

print text, '</>'
print repr(text), repr('</>')

if text is '</>':
    print 'Equal'
else:
    print 'Not equal!'
```

I simply want to compare two strings. For some reason, I need to concatenate characters to `text` one by one. I expected the if-statement to evaluate to `True` but it doesn't. And I am at a loss why!

Here's the output:

`</> </>
'</>' '</>'
Not equal!`

I am new to Python, and am using Python 2.7. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: @gdlmx I must have been looking in wrong places then. Thank you.

Comment: I never thought to look for difference between `is` and `==`, which is why I never found this post.

Comment: `is` check for the object identity, that is the direction in memory of the object not the value they contain, for that use `==`. Only the build-in constants are guaranty to evaluate the same with `is` and `==` that is why you see will stuff like `a is None` more often that `a == None` because the former is more idiomatic. So unless you are checking for `None` or if they are located in the same place (aka the point to the same thing) in memory, use `==`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `==` not `is`. `is` checks for object identity not equality.

e.g.

Let's say you have `foo` and `bar`:

```
>>> foo = 'green eggs and ham'
>>> bar = 'green eggs and ham'
>>> foo is bar
>>> False
>>> foo == bar
>>> True
```

On my machine:

```
>>> id(foo)
>>> 52008832 
>>> id(bar)
>>> 52010560
```

Now, check this out:

```
>>> foobar = bar
>>> foobar is bar
>>> True
```

This is true because we've aliased the variable foobar to point to bar which is a reference. Clearly, they reference the same location under this aliasing. Hence, is returns True.

More interestingly, consider two `ints`. This will only work for small ints (-5, 256).

```
>>> foo = 123
>>> bar = 123
>>> foo is bar
>>> True
>>> id(foo)
>>> 1993000432 # == id(bar)
```

`int`s (-5, 256) are cached and so ints within this range will eval to true using is for comparing object identity.

Comment: Thank you so much. It never crossed my mind to use `==` instead because I was under the impression that they were both the same. It solved my problem.

Comment: You are the best! xD I can't accept your answer for two more minutes. SOs policy.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used `is` in my entire history with Python (That might be because I am still having trouble wrapping my head around OOP). Just use the regular equality operator `==`.

Comment: Somebody gave me the impression that `is` is more Pythonic. I guess they were wrong. I would keep it in mind now onwards. Thanks :)